# Continuity of Integration for a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am having difficulties with this problem:

Let $f$ be a measurable function on $R$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_{-n}^{n} | f | = \int\limits_{R} | f | $

My idea is to use Continuity of integration:
We need an ascending collection of measurable sets. These are $E_n = R \cap [-n, n]$
$R = \bigcup E_n$
Now if we apply Continuity of Integration we have: 
$\lim_{R} |f| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{E_n} =\lim\limits \int_{-n}^{n} |f |$.
My problem is Continuity requires f to be intergrable and all i know is that f is measurable.

Another way i was thinking to use monotone convergence theorem, but i am not sure how to create the sequences.

Any Ideas? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Look at the sequence $f_n = \lvert f \rvert \cdot \chi_{[-n,n]}$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$.

Then:

> It should be easy to see that it is monotonic, and converges to $f$ pointwise.

Comment: so, using $f_n =|f| \chi_{[-n,n]}$ i can use now MCT and $\int_{R} |f| = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{R} f_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\int_{R-[-n,n]} f_n +\int_{[-n,n]} f_n) = 0 +  \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{[-n,n]} |f|$

Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. The key is that $\lvert f \rvert$ is nonnegative: it doesn't work otherwise (which is one difference from the improper Riemann integral).